# Strings with embedded variables in Python

Tags: python, string, variables, string-formatting

Maybe some already asked this but I didn't find it and I wanted to know how to embed variables into a string in Python. I usually do it like this:

```
print('Hi, my name is %s and my age is %d' %(name, age))
```

But sometimes is confusing and with ruby it would be like this

```
puts('Hi, my name is #{name} and my age is #{age}')
```

Is there any way to do in Python like I to it in Ruby?

Answer (score 9):

From Python 3.6 onwards, you can use an [*Formatting string literal*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (aka *f-strings*), which takes any valid Python expression inside `{...}` curly braces, followed by optional formatting instructions:

```
print(f'Hi, my name is {name} and my age is {age:d}')
```

Here `name` and `age` are both simple expressions that produce the value for that name.

In versions preceding Python 3.6, you can use [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), paired with either [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals()) or [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals()):

```
print('Hi, my name is {name} and my age is {age}'.format(**locals()))
```

As you can see the format is rather close to Ruby's. The `locals()` and `globals()` methods return namespaces as a dictionary, and the `**` keyword argument splash syntax make it possible for the `str.format()` call to access all names in the given namespace.

Demo:

```
>>> name = 'Martijn'
>>> age = 40
>>> print('Hi, my name is {name} and my age is {age}'.format(**locals()))
Hi, my name is Martijn and my age is 40
```

Note however that explicit is better than implicit and you should really pass in `name` and `age` as arguments:

```
print('Hi, my name is {name} and my age is {age}'.format(name=name, age=age)
```

or use positional arguments:

```
print('Hi, my name is {} and my age is {}'.format(name, age))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
dicta = {'hehe' : 'hihi', 'haha': 'foo'}
print 'Yo %(hehe)s %(haha)s' % dicta
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way that uses exactly Ruby's syntax for the format string:

```
import string
class RubyTemplate(string.Template):
    delimiter = '#'
```

Used as:

```
>>> t = RubyTemplate('Hi, my name is #{name} and my age is #{age}')
>>> name = 'John Doe'
>>> age = 42
>>> t.substitute(**locals())
'Hi, my name is John Doe and my age is 42'
```

You can then create a function such as:

```
def print_template(template, vars):
    print(RubyTemplate(template).substitute(**vars))
```

And use it as:

```
>>> print_template('Hi, my name is #{name} and my age is #{age}', locals())
Hi, my name is John Doe and my age is 42
```

---

On a side note: even python's `%` allow this kind of interpolation:

```
>>> 'Hi, my name is %(name)s and my age is %(age)d' % locals()
'Hi, my name is John Doe and my age is 42'
```

Comment: Actually this looks more complicated, I'm looking for something simple.

Comment: @AndresOrozco I never stated this was simpler, I just wanted to provide an alternative that matches ruby's "template syntax".

Comment: Yeah, But I was asking for something simple, like in Ruby.

Comment: @AndresOrozco The short answer for your question, which stated more clearly is "does python provide *automatic* string interpolation?", the answer is *no* and there is no way to do that. You can use `str.format`, use `%(name)s` but you must *always* pass explicitly the objects to interpolate. The only way to do automatic string interpolation is to hack the bytecode of functions to automatically insert the calls to `str.format`, but you probably cannot guarantee it will work correctly most of the time.

Answer (score -1):

`str.format` is the new way to do it, but this also works:

```
print('Hi, my name is %(name)s and my age is %(age)d' % {
   'name': name,
   'age': age,
})
```

Which is really the same as this, if the variables already exist:

```
print('Hi, my name is %(name)s and my age is %(age)d' % locals())
```